# Does my set function equal the Lebesgue Measure on subsets of $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ where $S\subseteq [0,1]$, and we define the following

- $I=[0,1]$
- $\left(I_k\right)_{k=1}^{m}$ are $m$ open sub-intervals of $I$
- $\ell(I)=1$ is the length of $I$
- $\ell(I_k)=c\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is the length of $I_k$ for $k=1,...,m$

$$\Omega(S\cap I_k)=\begin{cases} 
0 & S\cap I_k \ \text{is countable}\\
1 & S\cap I_k \ \text{is uncountable} \\ 
\end{cases}$$

$\mu^{*}(c,S)$ is the outer set function defined as

\begin{align*}
& \mu^{*}(c,S)=  \inf\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}c\ \Omega\left(S\cap I_{k}\right): S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k}\right\} 
\end{align*}

The inner set function $\mu_{*}(c,S)$ is

$\mu_{*}(c,S)=\mu^{*}(c,[0,1])-\mu^{*}(c, [0,1]\setminus S)$

And $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S)$ is defined when

$$\lim_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S)=\lim_{c\to 0}\mu^{*}(c,S)=\lim_{c\to 0}\mu_{*}(c,S)$$

Then

> Is $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S)$ equivelant to the Lebesgue Measure of $S$?

Comment: @Sayan So your saying $S_1$ is nowhere dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: $S_2$ is nowhere dense I think. I deleted my previous comment. There was an error. Cantor set when written in tertiary expansion has no $1$ and they have Lebesgue measure zero. For your case, you can consider a series of sets like

$C_0=[0,1]$, $C_1=[0,0.7) \cup [0.8,1]$. $C_1$ is the set which has no $7$ in the first place after the decimal point. Then you consider $C_2$ which has no $7$ in first two places after the decimal point and so on.

Comment: What about my set function. I know it’s hard to read but does it give the same result as the Lebesgue Measure.

Comment: Why is $\mu^{*}(c,S)=\mu_{*}(c,S)$? This does not seem obvious and I would guess that it would be wrong in many cases.

Comment: @supinf Can you give me an example?

Comment: Have you tried the cantor set? Also, currently it is not clear if it is a claim that you make or a question, so I thought maybe you had some proof for it.

Comment: $\mu^{*}(c,S)=\mu_{*}(c,S)$ is a claim, I have no proof. You can try setting $S$ to the cantor set but my question is if $\lim_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S_1)=\lambda(S_1)$ and $\lim_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S_2)=\lambda(S_2)$ if $S_1=\left\{\text{Numbers in [0,1] containing a 7 in at least one decimal place}\right\}$ and $S_2=\left\{\text{Numbers in [0,1] containing a 7 in no decimal place}\right\}$

Comment: Hey guys, apologies but I changed my question. I narrowed my post to one claim. I am hoping my set function equals the Lebesgue Measure on subsets of $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **negative**. In fact there is a set $S\subset[0,1]$ *of Lebesgue measure $0$* such that $S\cap(a,b)$ is uncountable for any $0\leqslant a<b\leqslant 1$ (thus, for such an $S$, we have $\mu^*(c,S)=1$ and $\mu_*(c,S)=0$ for any $0<c<1$). The idea to build $S$ is to take the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) and "fill in the holes" by its homothetic copies.

We define it explicitly. Let $S$ be the set of all numbers $x\in[0,1]$ *representable by a ternary fraction with only a finite number of $1$s*, i.e. such that there are $a_n\in\{0,1,2\}$, $n\geqslant 1$, with $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} a_n$, and the set $\{n : a_n=1\}$ is finite.

$S$ is clearly uncountable. Moreover, for any $n>0$ and $0\leqslant k<3^n$, the map $x\mapsto f_{n,k}(x):=3^{-n}(k+x)$ is a bijection between $S$ and $S\cap I_{n,k}$, where $I_{n,k}:=[3^{-n}k,3^{-n}(k+1)]$ (*informally, we prepend the $n$-digit ternary representation of $k$ to $x$ for $x\neq 1$*); thus, $S\cap I_{n,k}$ is uncountable too. But any open interval $(a,b)$, $0\leqslant a<b\leqslant 1$, contains an $I_{n,k}$ for some $n$ and $k$; thus, $S\cap(a,b)$ is uncountable as well.

Further, as promised again, $S=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\bigcup_{k=0}^{3^n-1}f_{n,k}(C)$, where $C$ is the Cantor set (for, take $1\neq x\in S$, let $n$ be the greatest with $a_n=1$ ($n=0$ if there's none), and let $k=\lfloor 3^n x\rfloor$; the reverse inclusion is clear). That is, $S$ is a countable union of sets of Lebesgue measure $0$. Then, $S$ itself has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: Is there any way to improve my set function so that it equals the Lebesgue measure

Comment: @Arbuja: Frankly, I don't know (if you insist on "counting" only). My feel is that attempts to do so range from "undecidable in ZFC" (if one binds tightly enough to $\mathbb{R}$; [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_set) and [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_measure_zero_set) are worth looking at, though not directly connected to your question) to "born to fail" (if one tries to go too abstract). But it's just what I feel.